# Sql 60 minutes interval Ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a subset of my data:

| Time | Name | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-10 14:11:15.000 | X | 111 |
| 2023-01-10 16:49:35.000 | X | 112 |
| 2023-01-10 16:51:35.000 | X | 110 |
| 2023-01-10 17:34:55.000 | X | 115 |
| 2023-01-10 17:35:55.000 | X | 111 |
| 2023-01-10 17:36:55.000 | X | 117 |
| 2023-01-10 17:37:21.000 | X | 116 |

I would like to rank the data by each Time And Name and Take the maximum Speed but only for 60 minutes interval from the first instace.
my output should be:

| rnk | Time | Name | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 14:11:15.000 | X | 111 (because there is no rows in the next 60 min interval) |
| 4 | 2023-01-10 16:49:35.000 | X | 112 |
| 6 | 2023-01-10 16:51:35.000 | X | 110 |
| 3 | 2023-01-10 17:34:55.000 | X | 115 |
| 5 | 2023-01-10 17:35:55.000 | X | 111 |
| 1 | 2023-01-10 17:36:55.000 | X | 117 |
| 2 | 2023-01-10 17:37:21.000 | X | 116 |

Because the first one is 16:49 and the next 60 minutes interval its untill 17:49 (on the same date on same name).. and so on for the next rows if was rows with 17:51 so check for the next 60 minutes interval.

Comment: Could you please explain what you have accomplished so far?

Comment: i did row number like this:
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY left([DateTime],13),X Order By Speed)
and it works good but not meet my conditions. it works for every hour but i need for an 60 minutes interval

Comment: If the highest speed in your raw data is 112, and your requirement is to *"Take the maximum Speed"* for each interval, I don't understand how your required output can have speeds higher than 112? I don't see how the 60 minute intervals ties into your required output either? Your description of the problem doesn't seem to correlate with the required output at all. Please can you clarify?

Comment: you are right, i fixed it.

Comment: How exactly do you define the 60 minutes intervals? For instance, if we add 17:50 with speed = 120, then we could look at 16:49 till 17:37 with speed = 117 being #1. Or we could look at 16:51 till 17:50 where suddenly speed 120 is #1 and speed = 117 only #2.

Comment: Pleased edit your question with what you have now and your one issue with that code you tried

Answer (score 1):

You have a *gaps and islands* problem, One method for solving it uses `LAG()` to get next row, then use the difference between `ROW_NUMBER()` and the running total of date difference using `SUM()` to create distinct groups :

```
WITH cte as (
  SELECT *, LAG(Time) over (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time) next_row,
            IIF(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(Time) over (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time), Time) <= 60, 1, 0) as date_diff
  FROM mytable
),
cte2 as (
  SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time) 
           - SUM(date_diff) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time) AS grp
  FROM cte
)  
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, grp ORDER BY Speed DESC ) as rnk,
       Time, Name, Speed
FROM cte2
ORDER BY Time
```

Results :

```
rnk Time                    Name    Speed
1   2023-01-10 14:11:15.000 X       111
4   2023-01-10 16:49:35.000 X       112
6   2023-01-10 16:51:35.000 X       110
3   2023-01-10 17:34:55.000 X       115
5   2023-01-10 17:35:55.000 X       111
1   2023-01-10 17:36:55.000 X       117
2   2023-01-10 17:37:21.000 X       116
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/P9FPGf6Z)

Comment: Thank you!
| 2023-10-01 16:49:35 | X             | 112           | 1            |
| 2023-10-01 16:51:35 | X             | 111           | 2            |
| 2023-10-01 17:34:55 | X             | 112           | 3            |
| 2023-10-01 17:35:55 | X             | 111           | 4            |
| 2023-10-01 17:36:55 | X             | 112           | 5            |
| 2023-10-01 17:37:21 | X             | 112           | 1     
( i ordered the rnk by grp and not by Speed just to make it more simple )
the 17:37 should also be in the same group..

Comment: I have revised my answer and improved it, please have a look

Comment: its still doesnt woeks well, i figured it out with While loop that itarets over 1 hour and index. Thank you anyways!

Comment: With the dataset you are sharing, it is working ! Could you edit your question and 
 share some simple data/expected output where you are experiencing issues ?

Comment: it works because the last date is 2023-10-01 17:37:21 | X | 112 | 1

if you had more date like 18:57:21 where its  shouldnt be in the same group  so also the 17:37:21 get another group

Comment: My mistake, I have edited my answer, can you check